# Spring mvc bind form data compound entity

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, data-binding

- In spring mvc how can i inside a controller bind post form data to an entity that has multiple relations to other entities?

The normal way to bind to a 'simple' entity is trivial...

```
save(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p, Group g, BindingResult result)
```

but if say, Person has 1*n relation to Cars(Set) and Car has a Set how can i have a form that once submitted, spring collects form data and populated all entities correctly?

Thanks,

Comment: You can check this [@LazyCollection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching), when set FALSE, it will not be LAZY and load the Set<>

Comment: For clarification i'm trying not to use a DTO.